# бот не принимает запросы от telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot

```
import data
import telebot
import os
from flask import request, Flask
from flask_sslify import SSLify

bot = telebot.TeleBot(data.token)

server = Flask(__name__)
sslify = SSLify(server)
#bot.remove_webhook();
#bot.set_webhook(data.webh_url_base+data.webh_url_path,
#               open(data.webh_ssl_cert,'r',encoding="utf_8"))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello, ' + message.from_user.first_name)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

@server.route(data.webh_url_path, methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    print(request.json())
    return "!", 200

@server.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url=data.webh_url_base+data.webh_url_path)
    return "!", 200

context = (data.webh_ssl_cert,data.webh_ssl_priv)
server.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=os.environ.get('PORT', data.webh_port),
           ssl_context = context)
```

При переходе по адресу, который слушает бот показывает эту страницу
[image: При переходе по адресу, который слушает бот показывает эту страницу]

> https://api.telegram.org/bot/getWebhookInfo

[image: здесь всё правильно]

Но при отправке сообщений боту, сервер никак не реагирует.

В чем проблема, и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно дело в том, что бот не хочет работать без прокси

```
from telebot import apihelper
apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://x.x.x.x:port'}
```

Comment: Да, дело было в том что скрипт был расположен на сервере в РФ, как только перенес на голландию всё заработало.